# How to add space between Date picker and button in form of html

Tags: javascript, html

I tried with code like

```
<form>
    Date: <input type="date" id="availableDate"/>

         <input type="button" value="Run" id="button1"> 
</form>
```

It showed up

[image]

How can I edit that code to have space between date picker and button like 
[image]

Comment: can you use margins?

Comment: you can also use `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are trying to add space of few pixels then you can use margin property.

```
<form>
    Date: <input type="date" id="availableDate"/>

         <input type="button" value="Run" id="button1" style="margin-left: 24px"> 
</form>
```